# How can I un-spam my domain while testing mailgun webhooks?

Tags: mailgun, email, spam-prevention

I managed to create all that code that creates mailgun webhooks plus many other things like record responses to local database.

During my tests I send emails to yahoo & gmail and of course - as you expected - I pressed a couple of times the spam button at my tablet's yahoo app to test and verify the events recorded with my code.

My problem is that now when I send to that yahoo address from the domain under test the email never reaches my inbox and at the logs I read:

```
4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 159.135.140.82 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes
```

See what mailgun reports:

```
{
    "severity": "temporary",
    "tags": [
        "issue 1",
        "newsletter",
        "2020"
    ],
    "mailing-list": {
        "list-id": "xyz101.mail.mysite.com",
        "sid": "1634752",
        "address": "xyz101@mail.mysite.com"
    },
    "storage": {
        "url": "https://storage.eu.mailgun.net/v3/domains/mail.mysite.com/messages/AgEFucSTB0eaifXAHzlNKbRoSH0IddfpZA==",
        "key": "AgEFucSTB0eaifXAHzlNKbRoSH0IddfpZA=="
    },
    "delivery-status": {
        "tls": true,
        "mx-host": "mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net",
        "attempt-no": 1,
        "description": "",
        "session-seconds": 0.39575695991516113,
        "retry-seconds": 600,
        "code": 421,
        "message": "4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 159.135.140.82 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes",
        "certificate-verified": true
    },
    "recipient-domain": "yahoo.co.uk",
    "id": "D5IqK77PRA29RvULyzXLsw",
    "campaigns": [],
    "reason": "generic",
    "user-variables": {
        "id": "15"
    },
    "flags": {
        "is-routed": false,
        "is-authenticated": true,
        "is-system-test": false,
        "is-test-mode": false
    },
    "log-level": "warn",
    "timestamp": 1604915932.781863,
    "envelope": {
        "transport": "smtp",
        "sender": "sales@mail.mysite.com",
        "sending-ip": "159.135.140.82",
        "targets": "blah-blah-blah@yahoo.co.uk"
    },
    "message": {
        "headers": {
            "to": "cent C. <blah-blah-blah@yahoo.co.uk>",
            "message-id": "20201109095852.1.8EC4631A16DA1C10@mail.mysite.com",
            "from": "mysite <sales@mail.mysite.com>",
            "subject": "test_MailGunHttpClient_send_from_real_domain_with_tags_with_tracking_opens_and_clicks_with_unsubscribe_enabled_and_with_recipient_variables_visible_to_webhooks_to_mailing_list_of_access_type_readonly"
        },
        "attachments": [],
        "size": 2130
    },
    "recipient": "blah-blah-blah@yahoo.co.uk",
    "event": "failed"
}
```

This message eventually will become `severity: "permanent"`.

Any idea how I can reverse this behavior at yahoo servers not accepting my emails(*)?

(*) For another domain I setup at Mailgun I inspect deliverability as I haven't clicked the spam button for emails landed from that domain

Comment: If there were a simple recipe to follow, spammers would use it. I guess the only advice is: stop doing it and wait?

Comment: if i project this situation to a real world scenario that means a sender of a list can't reach ANY of his subscribers at yahoo because one guy simply pressed the spam button?

Comment: http://www.smtp-error-codes.info/bounce/yahoo/bounce_421_4.7.0.php <- allegedly it means "try again in 4 hours", not necessarily "cannot reach"

Comment: hmmmm interesting...I also understand that the content of email plays a role like "is there unsubscribe button?" and 100s other factors that affect domain reputation...

Comment: ops, just delivered! nevertheless very difficult to test some cases!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about email deliverability are off-topic here. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam

Comment: if you notice iI'm writing code here....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your actions have had some repercussions, emails from one of our accounts using the same IP are blocked by Yahoo, Aol etc. And it started for no reason related to us, the recipients or the content of the emails (it is a paid newsletter).

[image]

Comment: Try first to testing web hooks with adapted tools provided by Mailgun, it's maybe the first step before suggest anything to someone who just answer you. Also try to understand the conditional side of it: "looks like" clearly means what I was talking about.

Comment: my webhooks work fine, no problem with my code; your answer (welcomed) verifies that is ip blocking and has nothing to do with me as i haven't send anything in bulk so far; eventually this post might help others if they face similar problem now or in the future